# Configure AIX Syslog to send application logs to Logstash on Remote Server

Tags: logstash, aix, syslog, elastic-stack

I am trying to ship an application log files to logstash. It runs on AIX, so I can't use filebeat. Has anyone configured syslog to send to logstash before?

I have an application that will write files to `/var/mqsi/log/application.log`
I want to pick that log up and forward to a remote server.

```
syslog.conf

mqsi.debug  /var/mqsi/log/application.log 
mqsi.debug       @10.123.445.217
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can send syslog events directly over the network to a remote server (ELK in our case) without writing it to a local file. No need to install anything extra on AIX.

Comment: I want to ship logs from AIX server to kafka broker. 

Below conf for logstash is not working

  "output" {
  "kafka" { 
    "bootstrap_servers" => "10.23.***.***:9092",
    "topic_id" =>  "my-topic",
 "ssl ca": "./usr/semasupp/LogShipper/PANTOMATH.GLOBAL.STANDARDCHARTERED.COM.cer",
 "ssl key": "./usr/semasupp/LogShipper/pantomath.global.standardchartered.com.ssl.key",
  }
},

  "files": [
    {
      "paths": [
        "/prd/ccsq/xib/data/trace/257/*"
      ],
      "fields": { "type": "syslog" }
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

You need switch to rsyslog.
Install rsyslog for AIX, then use syslog_ssw -r to switch.

Your rsyslog.conf should looks like

```
$ModLoad imfile
$InputFileName /var/mqsi/log/application.log
```

Comment: Ended up switching to rsyslog. The only issue, is the there is an additional package needed to enable TLS, which isn't built for AIX yet, so logs can only be sent in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I want to ship logs from AIX server to kafka broker.

Below conf for logstash is not working

```
 "output" {
  "kafka" { 
    "bootstrap_servers" => "10.23.***.***:9092",
    "topic_id" =>  "my-topic",
    "ssl ca": "./usr/semasupp/LogShipper/PANTOMATH.GLOBAL.STANDARDCHARTERED.COM.cer",
    "ssl key": "./usr/semasupp/LogShipper/pantomath.global.standardchartered.com.ssl.key",
  }
},

  "files": [
    {
      "paths": [
        "/prd/ccsq/xib/data/trace/257/*"
      ],
      "fields": { "type": "syslog" }
    }
  ]
}
```